# Partial specialization with member function type

Tags: c++

I want to convert `int __stdcall A::(int, int)` to `int __stdcall (A*, int, int)`.

My code is

```
class A {
public:
    int __stdcall B(int, int);
};

template<typename C, typename P1, typename P2>
struct Mem2Normal<int __stdcall C::(P1, P2)> {
    typedef int __stdcall (C*, P1, P2) type;
}; 

Mem2Normal<decltype(A::B)>::type
```

It caused a lot of syntax errors, how to fix it?

Comment: I don't know about the `__stdcall` (Microsoft-specific) but `std::bind(A::B, _1, _2, _3);` does the trick.  Reference [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For function *pointers*, the following works:

```
class A {
public:
    int __stdcall B(int, int);
};

template<typename>
struct Mem2Normal;

template<typename C, typename P1, typename P2>
struct Mem2Normal<int (__stdcall C::*)(P1, P2)> {
    typedef int __stdcall type(C*, P1, P2);
};

int main()
{
    Mem2Normal<decltype(&A::B)>::type x;
}
```

Comment: Note: `x` is a function here, not a function pointer. To make it a function pointer, either use `Mem2Normal<decltype(&A::B)>::type* x;` or inside `Mem2Normal` the nested `typedef int (__stdcall *type)(C*, P1, P2);`